# piece wise functions continuity

Tags: calculus, continuity

Find the value of ‘$k$’ that makes the function $h(x)$ everywhere continuous

$$h(x)=\begin{cases}x^2-k & x <-1\\
     x^3+3x^2+1  & x\geq -1\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

As any polynomial function is continuous

we need $$\lim_{x\to-1^-}h(x)=h(-1)=\lim_{x\to-1^+}h(x)$$